# How do you echo a question mark in a shell script?

Tags: xml, shell, escaping, echo

I want to write a script that writes an XML file.
I've been looking around, but I can't seem to find the way to `echo` the question mark from the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` XML declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ export version=1.0
$ export encoding=UTF-8
$ echo '<?xml version="'$version'" encoding="'$encoding'"?>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Single quote the constant string parts, leave the variables bare in the `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes around:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

Comment: If there were variables inside the single-quotes, would they expand?

Comment: no they won't expand. You need to close and reopen quote for variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '<?xml version="%s" encoding="%s"?>\n' "$VERSION" "$ENCODING"
```

This lets you use single quotes for the string (to avoid the need to escape double quotes inside a double-quoted string) and still include variable information.